Github Actions, run Terraform Apply and a custom Python Script
I have been using Terraform alongside Jenkins for the past few weeks, and for the purpose of learning, want to switch Jenkins with Github Actions.
Let me explain this next Jenkinsfile stage:
        stage('Deploy Infrastructure using Terraform & Update Porkbun Nameservers') {
            steps {
                parallel (
                    "Deploy Terraform": {
                        // Checkout IaC repository
                        sh "git clone https://www.github.com/assafdori/resume-app-iac.git"
                        
                        // Navigate to Terraform directory
                        dir('resume-app-iac') {
                            // Initialize Terraform
                            sh 'terraform init'

                            // Apply Terraform changes
                            sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve'
                        }
                    },
                    "Update Porkbun NS to AWS generated NS": {
                        // Sleep and wait for Terraform to propagate
                        sleep time: 180, unit: 'SECONDS'
                        
                        // Download the Python script that updates nameservers
                        sh 'curl -o update-ns.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/assafdori/resume-app-iac/main/update-ns.py'
                        
                        // Run the Python script that updates nameservers
                        sh 'python3 update-ns.py'
                    }
                )
            }
        }

This stage starts provisioning AWS resources using the Terraform configuration, it waits for 3 minutes, then runs a custom Python script that updates the name servers generated by Terraform with my external domain provider, Porkbun. It is important to mention that, as far as I'm aware, Terraform Apply won't be able to finish without the script running some time after Apply provisioned the hosted zones, because I have to point the name servers correctly.
I've been scratching my head how to achieve something similar with Github Actions. However, I am open to a different solution to this problem, if you think it's for the better.
I can provide the script itself, however I do not think it's necessary, it uses boto3 to fetch the name servers Terraform has created, and updates Porkbun name servers via API calls.
I think it's also important to mention that the point is to be able to provision everything from scratch, including the hosted zone which generates new name servers every time, hence the need for a script that will update the Porkbun side, and the end-to-end solution.
Just for the reference, here's some part of the Github Actions workflow:

      - name: Terraform Plan deployment
        working-directory: terraform
        run: terraform plan

    #   - name: Terraform Apply changes
    #     working-directory: terraform
    #     run: terraform apply -auto-approve

    ## SOMEHOW NEED THE SCRIPT TO RUN HERE, CONCURRENTLY WITH TERRAFORM APPLY



Why not trigger that python script from within terraform? ... look into null_resource or terraform_data ... and the hardcoded wait you can do better and have it on a loop inside the script to check if the resource is ready, with a hardcoded wait you waste time or run into the case that the resource is not ready

There is also a python provider: https://github.com/joaqquin89/terraform-provider-python ... sounds like a nice alternative but I've never use it
